# Zeros of non-trivial solution of linear ODE of second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

The exercise is as follows: Prove that an arbitrary non-trivial solution of $x''+tx=0$ on interval $[-25,25]$ has at least $25$ and at most $28$ zeros/roots. How am I supposed to do this? I tried splitting the interval and using standard criteria but I get to many solutions.

I tried the following: I know that the distance between two consecutive zeros $t_1,t_2, t_2>t_1$ of $x''+q(t)x=0$ on interval $\mathbb{I}$ is $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{M}}<t_2-t_1<\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{m}},$$
where $M:=\sup_{\mathbb{I}}q(t)$ and $m:=\inf_{\mathbb{I}}q(t)$. And $q(t)>0$ on $\mathbb{I}$.

On the other hand we know that $x''+q(t)x=0$ has at most one zero on interval $\mathbb{I}$ if $q(t)<0$.

Knowing this I split the interval into $[-25,-1], (-1,1)$ and $ [1,25]$. Calculating the distance between zeros I got that on the first interval we have one zero at most. On the second I have no clue, but on the third there are at most like $38.$ However, I am not sure whether these are all possible zeros or just of one solution and if it is just of one solution I don't know whether that solution with that many zeros is a solution on the whole interval.

Comment: I don't know if you can edit your question, but please show the approach that you've tried up to the step where you got stuck.

Comment: A hand-wavy hint: try to refine the inequality you have, by considering how the original inequality is proved.

Answer (score 1):

This is an algorithmic solution, that does not give exactly the solution provided by the OP.

Assuming a zero in $t_k$, the previous zero $t_{k-1}<t_k$ should satisfy on the interval $[t_{k-1},t_k]$
$$
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{t_k}}<t_k-t_{k-1}<\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{t_{k-1}}}
$$
so the minimum distance is when
$$
t_{k-1}=t_k-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{t_k}}\quad\land\quad t_{k-1}>0\tag1
$$
while the maximum distance is when
$$
t_k-t_{k-1}<\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{t_{k-1}}}
$$
i.e. $t_{k-1}$ is a solution of
$$
t_{k-1}(t_k-t_{k-1})^2=\pi^2\quad\land\quad0<t_{k-1}<t_k\tag2
$$
By calculating the sequence of values of $(1)$ starting with $t_k=25$ we get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 24.3717 \\
 2 & 23.7353 \\
 3 & 23.0905 \\
 4 & 22.4367 \\
 5 & 21.7735 \\
 6 & 21.1002 \\
 7 & 20.4163 \\
 8 & 19.721 \\
 9 & 19.0135 \\
 10 & 18.2931 \\
 11 & 17.5585 \\
 12 & 16.8088 \\
 13 & 16.0425 \\
 14 & 15.2582 \\
 15 & 14.4539 \\
 16 & 13.6276 \\
 17 & 12.7766 \\
 18 & 11.8977 \\
 19 & 10.9869 \\
 20 & 10.0391 \\
 21 & 9.04756 \\
 22 & 8.00312 \\
 23 & 6.89261 \\
 24 & 5.69599 \\
 25 & 4.37966 \\
 26 & 2.87849 \\
 27 & 1.0268 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
while for the sequence $(2)$ we get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 24.3635 \\
 2 & 23.7185 \\
 3 & 23.0643 \\
 4 & 22.4005 \\
 5 & 21.7265 \\
 6 & 21.0417 \\
 7 & 20.3452 \\
 8 & 19.6362 \\
 9 & 18.9138 \\
 10 & 18.177 \\
 11 & 17.4244 \\
 12 & 16.6545 \\
 13 & 15.8658 \\
 14 & 15.0562 \\
 15 & 14.2232 \\
 16 & 13.3638 \\
 17 & 12.4743 \\
 18 & 11.5499 \\
 19 & 10.5843 \\
 20 & 9.56866 \\
 21 & 8.4905 \\
 22 & 7.33014 \\
 23 & 6.05324 \\
 24 & 4.58627 \\
 25 & 2.66006 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In the first case, in which we are maximising the number of zeroes, we should take into account a possible zero in $25$ and another in $t<0$, reaching a maximum of $29$ zeroes. In the second case we have nothing to add, and obtain a minimum of $25$ zeroes.